# pub get failed : A package may not list itself as a dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, grid, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I'm having this problem in **pubspec.yaml** :

here the **pubspec.yaml** :

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  pluto_grid: ^2.9.3
```

and here is the Error :

```
[pluto_grid] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in pluto_grid...                      
Error on line 37, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
   ╷
37 │   pluto_grid: ^2.9.3
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

need to know what's wrong, used the same in other project and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I found why i'm getting this Error, this happens because the project name is the same as the library name.
so if you have the same Error as this just try to change the project name.

Comment: The error message told you exactly what was wrong. Was the message confusing?  How could it be improved?

Comment: @jamesdlin Maybe something like [Mosayeb Masoumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72288069/851045)'s answer can improve the message.

Comment: Why would someone name their project the same as one of its dependencies?

Comment: did the same mistake with project name  'hive' 

Answer (score 8):

the project package name should not be the same name of added library's name in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 4):

had the same issue, changing the filename resolved it.
The problem was that the filename and dependency name was the same.

Change your project name and try again.

Answer (score 3):

change you project name than solve [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg4uY.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

That's not necessary to declare your own project as a dependency in the project's pubspec.yaml

Comment: i didn't notice first time that my project name was the same as the library name. i was so confused why i was getting the Error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happen when your project name same as package name. So rename your project name.